# Add current path to command parameter

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to execute a Cmd command with parameters:

```
@ECHO OFF
.\someCommand.exe /log verbose.log
```

If I only provide the log file without a directory, then, for an undetermined reason, the command writes the logfile into some temporary folder.

So if I want to have logging into the file `verbose.log` in the same directory the command is in, I would have to call:

```
.\someCommand.exe /log C:\full\path\to\this\directory\verbose.log
```

However, that full path changes from system to system, and I want a single batch file that works on all systems (as long as the batch file is in the same directory as the `someCommand.exe`). How can I get that path into that command line parameter?

Comment: More information on the real executable, _name and location and perhaps whether it is in `%PATH%` and/or local to the batch file, run as Administrator etc._ would help.

Comment: To reference the folder the batch is in use `%~dp0verbos.log` To use the current path as in `.\someCommand` use `.\verbose.log`

Comment: @Alexander, if you know it is a duplicate question, wouldn't it be prudent to just delete your question?